# Minimum includes for Alfresco Share custom page?

Tags: share, yui, alfresco, freemarker

I am creating a custom Share page that must have none of the Alfresco UI on it, but which still needs access to the Alfresco and YAHOO objects.

I have successfully created the page and caused it to open in a new tab, but I get errors that the Alfresco and YAHOO objects are undefined.

What are the minimum includes I must add to my Freemarker template to get access to those objects?

Update: I have gotten the Alfresco and YAHOO objects to load, but now am getting "Uncaught Error: extend failed, please check that all dependencies are included."

Here are the freemarker and javascript includes I've got so far, if it'll help:

```
<#import "import/alfresco-common.ftl" as common />

...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/ajax/yahoo/yahoo-min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/ajax/yahoo/connection/connection-min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/ajax/common.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/ajax/utilities/utilities.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../yui/yuiloader/yuiloader.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/alfresco.js"> </script>
```

Update 2: Based on the first answer, the first few lines of the template look like this and again yield Uncaught ReferenceError: YAHOO is not defined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <region-id>head-resources</region-id>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

        <title></title>
        <script>
             var urlParams;
```

Update 3: I've reduced the source to the minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. What follows next is the template component definition file, followed by the freemarker template itself. Definition:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<page>
   <title>iPad Viewer</title>
   <title-id>page.iPad.title</title-id>
   <description>iPad Viewer</description>
   <description-id>page.iPad.description</description-id>
   <template-instance>viewer-ipad</template-instance>
   <authentication>user</authentication>
</page>
```

Freemarker template:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="content">
         <@region-id>head-resources</@region-id>
         <script>
         alert(YAHOO);
         alert(Alfresco);
         </script>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Error is:

```
Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "org/alfresco/viewer-ipad.ftl" in line 11, column 7: Unclosed @... when the end of the file was reached.
```

Comment: You mean without the Alfresco headers etc?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you created the page, but this is not needed when you define your regions.

Probably there are all in the `<region-id>head-resources</region-id>` So if you include that in the page-template that should suffice.

Comment: I don't have regions. The page must have none of the Alfresco Share UI on it. No regions, no headers, no side menu, no footers.

Comment: Yes but the sources you'll need like I posted. That should be enough. Try it and let me know.

Comment: I deleted my other includes and inserted your region-id tag just below the head tag. I've updated my question to reflect the new template and the results.

Comment: Hi Dan, can you post your template.xml where you define the components. And do check that all the sources from head-resources are loaded.

Comment: Posted. Template parser's choking on the '<@region-id>' tags.